# How to get stream url and key from AWS MediaLive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, live-streaming, aws-media-live, amazon-ivs

I need to design a solution where I take a Zoom live stream as input and save chunks of duration 10 seconds in a s3 bucket. I need to save them in bucket for using AWS Transcribe on them.

For live streaming to a custom client, Zoom takes a stream url and stream key. I first tried to use AWS IVS for streaming. IVS gives a stream url and key which I supplied to zoom. But I didn't find a solution to intercept the stream and store audio chunks in s3.

Next I found about MediaLive which seemed promising as it takes an input source and output destination. I set the input type as RTMP (Push) but I am not getting a stream url or stream key that I can send to Zoom.

How can I get these stream url and key? Or is it that I am approaching it all wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your message.  The RTMP details belong to the MediaLive Input you defined, independent of whatever Channel to which  the Input might be attached.  Have a look at the Inputs section in your Console.

Alternatively, you can run a command like this from your AWS CLI or your CloudShell prompt:

```
aws medialive describe-input --input-id 1493101
.
{
    "Arn": "arn:aws:medialive:us-west-2:123456123456:input:1493107",
    "AttachedChannels": [],
    "Destinations": [
        {
            "Ip": "44.222.111.85",
            "Port": "1935",
            "Url": "rtmp://44.222.111.85:1935/live/1"
        }
    ],
    "Id": "1493107",
    "InputClass": "SINGLE_PIPELINE",
    "InputDevices": [],
    "InputPartnerIds": [],
    "InputSourceType": "STATIC",
    "MediaConnectFlows": [],
    "Name": "RTMP-push-6",
    "SecurityGroups": [
        "313985"
    ],
    "Sources": [],
    "State": "DETACHED",
    "Tags": {},
    "Type": "RTMP_PUSH"
}
.
```

The two parameters after the ":1935/" in the URL are the App name and Instance name. They should be unique and not blank. You can use simple values as per my example.  The stream key can be left blank on your transmitting device.

You can test the connectivity into the MediaLive Channel using an alternate source of RTMP to confirm the cloud side is listening correctly.  There are various phone apps that will push RTMP;  ffmpeg also works.

I suggest adding a VOD source to your medialive channel as the first source to your channel in order to confirm the channel starts correctly and produces a short bit of good output to your intended destinations. All the metrics and alarms should be healthy. When that works as intended, then switch to your intended RTMP input.

You can monitor network-in bytes and input video frame rate metrics from AWS CloudWatch. Channel event logs will also be logged to CloudWatch *if* you enable the Channel logging option on your MediaLive channel (recommended).
I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try this out. Also, can you tell how to create these security groups? I am trying to stream using OBS Studio and can't figure out which IP addresses to add in security groups.

Answer (score 0):

Input security groups can be created from the AWS MediaLive Console or via the AWS CloudShell CLI, or your local aws-cli, using a command of the form:
'aws medialive create-input-security-group'.   Add the 'help' parameter for details on syntax.